# update table help

Tags: sql

i have  two tables: table_1 and table_2

```
table_1                       table_2
field_1   field_2             field_3      field_4
1          a                  1             
2          b                  4
3          c                  3
4          d                  2
```

now i need a query using update so that in table_2 i can have follwing values in field_4:

```
table_2
field_3    Field_4
1              a
4              d
3              c
2              b
```

should be obtained by update staement in single query  using table_1 such that if field_3 of table_2 has 1 then  filed_4  should have value equlas to field_2, field_1 in table_1

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, it would be:

```
UPDATE table_2
 set field_4 = t1.field_2
 from table_2 t2
  inner join table_1 t1
   on t1.Field1 = t2.Field_3
```

This assumes that field_1 is a primary keys (has unique values). Anything in table_2 not found in table_1 would not be updated. Duplicate field_3 values in table_2 would be properly set.

Comment: I didn't try, but in sql server I think it needs to be _UPDATE t2_

Comment: It doesn't have to be, unless the table being updated is joined on itself (UPDATE X from X inner join X), in which case it gets a bit too complex to discuss in a comment box.

Comment: +1, I tried it both ways: _UPDATE table_2_ and _UPDATE t2_ and both work.  I generally tend to do _UPDATE alias_ when I use an alias in a joined update.

Comment: thanx but i need update ststement without using join plz help as soon aspossible

Comment: Didn't realise that we couldn't use joins--but why not? What about subqueries or nested queries? What are the real constraints to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, since you aliased the tables, I think he's right.  The correct answer would be:

```
    UPDATE t2
       SET field_4 = t1.field_2
      FROM    table_2 t2
       INNER JOIN
          table_1 t1
       ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field_3
```

Comment: thanx  but i need   update ststement without using join  plz help as soon aspossible